# Import Pybind11/C++ compiled module not working

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I'm fairly new to python setuptools and dist. I can't seem to get a c++ wrapper module to import so that I may use the functions.

The compiled .so file shows up in the installed-files.txt after pip install but yet importing the wrapper does not.

**setup.py**

```py
import subprocess
import os
from pathlib import Path

from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext


class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Extension.__init__(self, name, sources=[])


class CMakeBuild(build_ext):
    def run(self):
        for ext in self.extensions:
            self.build_cmake(ext)
        super().run()

    def build_cmake(self, ext):
        try:
            subprocess.check_output(["cmake", "--version"])
        except OSError:
            raise RuntimeError(
                "CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: "
                + ", ".join(e.name for e in self.extensions)
            )

        cwd = Path().absolute()

        # these dirs will be created in build_py, so if you don't have
        # any python sources to bundle, the dirs will be missing
        build_temp = Path(self.build_temp)
        build_temp.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        extdir = Path(self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name))
        extdir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

        pyenv_root = os.environ.get("PYENV_ROOT")

        cmake_args = [
            f"-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY={extdir}",
            "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release",
            "-DTRANSIT_INCLUDE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF",
        ]

        if pyenv_root is not None:
            cmake_args += [f"-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE={pyenv_root}/shims/python"]

        build_args = ["--config", "Release", "--", "-j2"]

        env = os.environ.copy()

        self.announce("Running CMake prepare", level=3)
        subprocess.check_call(["cmake", cwd] + cmake_args, cwd=build_temp, env=env)

        self.announce("Building extensions")
        cmake_cmd = ["cmake", "--build", "."] + build_args
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_cmd, cwd=build_temp)


setup(
    name="bgtfs_py_lib",
    version="3.2.2",
    long_description="",
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        "redis==2.10.6",
        "cffi==1.11.5",
        "numpy==1.15.3",
        "patricia-trie==10",
        "PuLP==1.6.8",
        "py-lz4framed==0.13.0",
        "pycparser==2.19",
        "pyparsing==2.2.2",
        "pypng==0.0.18",
        "pyproj==1.9.5.1",
        "python-graph-core==1.8.2",
        "pytz==2018.6",
        "redis==2.10.6",
        "requests==2.21.0",
        "six==1.11.0",
        "tabulate==0.8.2",
        "unicodecsv==0.14.1",
        "Unidecode==1.0.22",
    ],
    ext_modules=[CMakeExtension("bgtfs_py_lib.bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper")],
    cmdclass=dict(build_ext=CMakeBuild),
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests"]),
    package_data={"": "*.so"},
)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper)
include(submodules/transitLib/bgtfs/bgtfsLib/TransitUtils/transit_shared.cmake)

# bgtfsPyLib
set(PYBIND11_CPP_STANDARD -std=c++14)
set(PYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION 3.6)

add_subdirectory(submodules/transitLib transitLib)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)

include_directories(
    cpp
    submodules/transitLib/bgtfs/bgtfsLib/
    submodules/transitLib/bgtfs/bgtfsLib/bgtfsLib
)

pybind11_add_module(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper MODULE NO_EXTRAS
    cpp/pybindCasts.cpp
    cpp/bgtfsPyLibWrapper.cpp
    cpp/BgtfsFeedHandler.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper PRIVATE transitLib)
set_target_properties(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper PROPERTIES
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bgtfs_py_lib
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bgtfs_py_lib
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bgtfs_py_lib
)
target_compile_definitions(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper PRIVATE TRANSIT_SERVER)
target_compile_definitions(transitLib PRIVATE TRANSIT_SERVER)
target_compile_definitions(bgtfsLib PRIVATE ENABLE_BACKWARD_FILE_COMPATIBILITY YES)
set_default_target_properties(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper)
```

I am trying to use virtualenv in order to isolate the modules required to run in my project.

Here is the file struct:

```
.
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- README.md
|-- bgtfs_py_lib
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- bgtfs_handler
|-- cpp
|   |-- BgtfsFeedHandler.cpp
|   |-- BgtfsFeedHandler.h
|   |-- bgtfsPyLibWrapper.cpp
|   `-- pybindCasts.cpp
|-- deploy.sh
|-- make.sh
|-- pybind11
|-- setup.py
|-- submodules
|-- test.sh
`-- tests
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- __pycache__
    |-- fixtures
    |-- test.py
    `-- test_functions.py
```

The **init**.py file in bgtfs_py_lib looks like this. The functions of the wrapper are being exposed.

```
import bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper as _bgtfs_py_lib
from bgtfs_py_lib.bgtfs_handler.bgtfs_handler import BgtfsHandler
```

In the other project it is being pip installed using git+ssh and egg .

> git+ssh://git@github.com/path/to/project.git@build/production/setup#egg=bgtfs_py_lib

When I **ctrl+space** in pyCharm the wrapper module is found and the Classes are present.
The module is located in Binary Skeletons directory but yet

**import bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper as _bgtfs_py_lib** just simply does not work and the following exception is thrown: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper'`

Can someone please help me figure out how to properly build C++/Pybind11 modules and use them in a pip installed package with virtualenv?

Comment: Are you able to import module without install?

Comment: Instead of specifying DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY you can do the following trick:  https://github.com/sizmailov/pyxmolpp2/blob/master/setup.py#L42-L44 . I have no troubles with pip installation.

Comment: The wrapper classes are still not visible on import

Comment: I'm not having trouble with pip install, I'm having trouble importing the classes in the .so file that gets generated

Comment: You changed library output directory. Check that after install your `.so ` files appear in `local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/`

Comment: do you suggest I remove these lines
```set_target_properties(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper PROPERTIES
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bgtfs_py_lib
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bgtfs_py_lib
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bgtfs_py_lib
)```

Comment: @Sergei at this location: ~/.pyenv/versions/bgtfsPyLib/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bgtfs_py_lib/bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper.cpython-36m-darwin.so/ the directory is empty

Comment: I think it should be shared library rather than directory: `~/.pyenv/versions/bgtfsPyLib/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bgtfs_py_lib/bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper.cpython-36m-darwin.so`

Comment: Are you able to build and use your extension with Cmake only, without pip? Pip needs just to run cmake and place generated `.so` into right place. Check first `.so` generation step. Then check that they go to corresponding place.

Comment: I am able to build and use the extension with Cmake only

Comment: So the project that imports it can see the .so file and its classes, but the library itself cannot

Comment: You should post answer to your own question and mark it as a "solution" rather than updating the question. Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 3):

I have finally solved it

Turns out the CMakeLists.txt needed to be changed because it there was inconsistencies between the cmake_args and the build_args. So the CMakeList.txt file now looks like this:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper)
include(submodules/transitLib/bgtfs/bgtfsLib/TransitUtils/transit_shared.cmake)

# bgtfsPyLib
set(PYBIND11_CPP_STANDARD -std=c++14)
set(PYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION 3.6)

add_subdirectory(submodules/transitLib transitLib)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)

include_directories(
    cpp
    submodules/transitLib/bgtfs/bgtfsLib/
    submodules/transitLib/bgtfs/bgtfsLib/bgtfsLib
)

pybind11_add_module(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper MODULE NO_EXTRAS
    cpp/pybindCasts.cpp
    cpp/bgtfsPyLibWrapper.cpp
    cpp/BgtfsFeedHandler.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper PRIVATE transitLib)
target_compile_definitions(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper PRIVATE TRANSIT_SERVER)
target_compile_definitions(transitLib PRIVATE TRANSIT_SERVER)
target_compile_definitions(bgtfsLib PRIVATE ENABLE_BACKWARD_FILE_COMPATIBILITY YES)
set_default_target_properties(bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper)
```

and the setup.py file is now:

**setup.py**

```py
import subprocess
import os
from pathlib import Path

from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext


class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Extension.__init__(self, name, sources=[])


class CMakeBuild(build_ext):
    def run(self):
        for ext in self.extensions:
            self.build_cmake(ext)
        super().run()

    def build_cmake(self, ext):
        try:
            subprocess.check_output(["cmake", "--version"])
        except OSError:
            raise RuntimeError(
                "CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: "
                + ", ".join(e.name for e in self.extensions)
            )

        cwd = Path().absolute()

        # these dirs will be created in build_py, so if you don't have
        # any python sources to bundle, the dirs will be missing
        if not os.path.exists(self.build_temp):
            os.makedirs(self.build_temp)
        extdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name)))

        pyenv_root = os.environ.get("PYENV_ROOT")

        cmake_args = [
            f"-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY={extdir}",
            "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release",
            "-DTRANSIT_INCLUDE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF",
        ]

        if pyenv_root is not None:
            cmake_args += [f"-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE={pyenv_root}/shims/python"]

        build_args = ["--config", "Release", "--", "-j2"]

        env = os.environ.copy()

        self.announce("Running CMake prepare", level=3)
        subprocess.check_call(["cmake", cwd] + cmake_args, cwd=self.build_temp, env=env)

        self.announce("Building extensions")
        cmake_cmd = ["cmake", "--build", "."] + build_args
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_cmd, cwd=self.build_temp)


setup(
    name="bgtfs_py_lib",
    version="3.2.2",
    author="Transit App",
    author_email="juan@transitapp.com",
    description="A python wrapper for the transitLib",
    long_description="",
    zip_safe=False,
    license="Transit",
    install_requires=[
        "bgtfs_py_lib",
        "redis==2.10.6",
        "cffi==1.11.5",
        "numpy==1.15.3",
        "patricia-trie==10",
        "PuLP==1.6.8",
        "py-lz4framed==0.13.0",
        "pycparser==2.19",
        "pyparsing==2.2.2",
        "pypng==0.0.18",
        "pyproj==1.9.5.1",
        "python-graph-core==1.8.2",
        "pytz==2018.6",
        "redis==2.10.6",
        "requests==2.21.0",
        "six==1.11.0",
        "tabulate==0.8.2",
        "unicodecsv==0.14.1",
        "Unidecode==1.0.22",
    ],
    ext_modules=[CMakeExtension("bgtfs_py_lib_wrapper")],
    cmdclass=dict(build_ext=CMakeBuild),
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests", "*.plist"]),
    package_data={"": "*.so"},
)
```

The extension file was not to be outputted into the bgtfs_py_lib directory but rather the virtual environment instead and the project itself was to be required

Shout out to [Sergei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741477/sergei) for the help figuring things out